# Host java website on Linux KVM

Tags: java, apache, dns, hosting, vps

I have a Linux KVM with hostgator and my domain name with Godaddy, I'm running my JSP website on Hostgator using Apache server but the problem is when M tring to access my website with domain name it is not coming but if m doing www.domainname.com:8080/WebsiteName then m able to access my website. Please help me in making it www.domainname.com instead of www.domainname.com:8080/WebsiteName.

Comment: I voting to close this post because this is not a programming question rather infrastructure question so this best suitable for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

open your Godaddy account setting add the `ip address` and `Nameserver` of the `hostgator` and also change the port no. with 8080.

godaddy default use own dns and ip address and you are using hostgator web hosting and godaddy domain manager, so you need to map and point domain to hostgator with ip address. you can fine your ip other info from setting and managing of hostgator. you can also contact with the customer care of both service provider to performing this task.

you can find image below 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Mayank, I dont have any record entry here with godaddy nither m allowed to make here

Comment: then you need to contact with the customer care of the `godaddy` me sure there is something wrong. you can get the `ip and dns information` of the server on mail from customer care and use `hostgator`  customer care to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0blj8.png)

Hi Mayank, I dont have any record entry here with godaddy nither m allowed to make here